# Array initialization differences java

Tags: java

What is the difference between the two following methods of array initialization:

1. `Object[] oArr = new Object[] {new Object(), new Object()};`
2. `Object[] oArr = {new Object(), new Object()};`

Is it related to heap/stack allocation?

Thanks!

Comment: There' no difference.

Comment: "premature optimization is the root of all evil"

Comment: @ Carl Manaster: this should be your answer.

Comment: Thanks, @Naveed, but it's too short for an answer.

Comment: @gulbrandr: It would only be premature optimization if the OP believed them to do the same thing, and was asking which one was faster. It's not an "optimization" question when he's asking whether there are any differences between the two - if they *behave* differently, that's far more important than optimization.

Comment: The second one can only be used for initialisation, the first for can be used for assignment, or as an expression as well.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: you are right. I should probably remove my comment.

Answer (score 22):

None at all - they're just different ways of expressing the same thing.

The second form is only available in a variable declaration, however. For example, you cannot write:

```
foo.someMethod({x, y});
```

but you can write:

```
foo.someMethod(new SomeType[] { x, y });
```

The relevant bit of the Java language specification is section [10.6 - Array Initializers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6):

> An *array initializer* may be specified in a declaration, 
>   or as part of an array creation expression (§15.10), creating an array and providing some initial values:

Comment: @gasan: Yes, that's part of an array creation expression... I don't see how that goes against anything in my answer.

Comment: I think it would be better to add that inside a method, `return new SomeType[] {x, y};` is *valid* but `return {x, y};` is *invalid*.

Comment: @PriyanshulGovil: I don't see why it's worth highlighting return statements specifically. I've already given one example, as well as the general case of the second form being available in a variable declaration. A return statement is not a variable declaration, therefore it's invalid in that context.

Comment: Oh, I was seeing another question in parallel, which asked the difference between both `new SomeType[] {..}` and `{..}` (not specifically during assignment), and I commented on the wrong question. I'm sorry.

Comment: Although, `SomeType object = SomeFunction()` is still initialization of `object` from a function which returns `SomeType`.

Comment: @PriyanshulGovil: Yes, but the return statement isn't part of the variable declaration in that case. I'd be *really* surprised if anyone read my answer and expected to be able to use `return {x, y};`

Comment: Haha, I was actually trying that. That's how I stumbled here ;)

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely identical.  The second is allowed shorthand for the first (only when, as here, it is done as part of a variable declaration.

Answer (score 1):

In Java all objects live in the heap, as arrays are objects in Java they lives in the stack.

for these two there is no difference in result, you 'll got two array objects with the same elements.

However sometimes you will encounter some situations where you can't use them, for example you don't know the elements of the array. then you get stuck with this form:

`Object [] array=new Object[size];`

Answer (score 0):

There is a small and catchy difference still!

You can do

```
int[] arr;
arr= {1,2,3}; // Illegal
```

But you can very well do

```
int[] arr;
arr = new [] {1,2,3} //Legal
```

Also if you are to initialize later then you cannot do

```
int arr;
arr = new [] {1,2,3} //Illegal
```